# Problem with php bin2hex function

Tags: php, string, hex

I am using the php function bin2hex on some strings, and one of them have a division sign character ÷ (Dec: 247, Hex: f7).

But when I try:

```
echo bin2hex('÷');
```

I get:

```
c3b7
```

The first problem is that the c3 character was added and I have no idea where it comes from (c2 also gets added before other characters).

And the second and main problem, php is giving me the hex string "b7" as a representation of the division sign ÷, but b7 represents · and not ÷.

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your source code is Unicode-encoded so that your editor encodes '÷' in unicode (eg. UTF-8). "c3b7" is two-byte encoded form of '÷' (See [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f7/index.htm)). Make sure your source code is ASCII-encoded to get the effect you desire.

Comment: A lot of people can get confused by UTF of any form. UTF-8 UTF-16LE UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, or UTF-32BE.

Comment: How can I get my php saved as ASCII-Encoded? I am using gedit on linux. I have also tried from console with `root:~$ php -r "echo bin2hex('÷');"` and I get the same output: c3b7.

Comment: @Manhim : Thank you, now with `bin2hex(utf8_decode('÷'));` I get f7 as output.

Comment: That is because your terminal's charset is unicode too. You can use Notepad++ to switch between charsets on Windows. On Linux, you can use iconv to convert charsets: `iconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code ASCII --output myASCII.file myUTF8.source`